# Define Variable with Multiple Type in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, telerik

I have two functions with thw same code but type of first parameter may be RadCombobox and in other case be RadDropDownlist .
how to make one function of the code and the type of first parameter change??[image]

Comment: Screenshots can't be compiled. Post your *code*, not an image of your code

Comment: As for how - that's what inheritance and generics are for. Do those controls have some common class, that implements DataSource,DataValueField etc? Create a method that accepts this class, instead of concrete classes

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos (considers posting an image of a solution...)

Comment: What platform are you using?

Comment: @Nawal_Falthy there are a lot of RadComboBox controls - Winforms, ASP.NET Webforms, ASP.NET MVC. Each has its own properties and hierarchy. Some of these properties are provided by the platform itself

Answer (score 0):

If the two classes, `RadDropDownlist` and `RadComboBox`, do have the same base class, can you use the nearest base class that contains those properties. If these properties do not exist on the base class, you can't use inheritance.

As a sort-of-solution, you then might consider reflection or `dynamic`, but I would not use those. Then keep the two methods.